# Derivative of a sum in Theano

Tags: python, theano, derivative

So I want to calculate the gradient and Hessian of the following sum. Afaik Theano should be able to do that, however I can't figure out how. 
X is a Matrix of size M x N; y M sized vector; beta a N sized vector.

[image]

One way to compute the sum is using the scan() function, which I did like this:

```
 res,ups =  theano.scan(lambda v,w: v*np.log(1/(1+np.exp(-1*w.dot(beta))))
         +((1-v)*(np.log(1/(1+np.exp(w.dot(beta)))))), sequences = [y,X])

 t7 = theano.function(inputs = [X,y,beta],outputs = res)
```

and that works fine as far as I can tell. However, I can't use this as an Input for the grad() function with respect to beta. 
So what I would like to know is if there is a way to either use the scan function as input of the grad function or a different way to compute the sum.

(I first tried in sympy, but sympy can't lambdify Indexedbase objects, so I can compute the grad but can't use it as a function, maybe that helps? )

The Sum adds up a function of the Dot Product of a line in X and beta while the binary vector y decides which of two functions will be used.

```
 log(1/(1+exp(-X_i*beta)))
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: do you mind explaining how the sum is related to the matrix and vectors?

Comment: if i understand your art i think you can simplify your expression using the basic properties of logarithms. The bases are the same, right (e+1)?

Comment: The problem that I need to differentiate a sum of Matrix entries cannot be calculated away I'm afraid, since the e^X*beta does not cancel out